# Is there an automatic way to replace tab and images, instead of Find and Replace in Adobe Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

I am writing a textbook with Adobe InDesign that has optional sections. These sections have a tab then a flag at the right end of the tabs. I am wondering if in the TOC, how should I treat the TOC prior to refain myself to Find (the tab and image) and Replace (to styled text) at each updates of TOC?

[image: This is the example after treatment.]

This is the example after treatment.

Comment: I'm not really understanding this question.

Comment: @Scott My understanding is they want the _(opt)_ "flag" in the TOC-entry to use a different character style, so I propose [using a GREP style](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/76790/4003)

Answer (score 1):

You can use InDesign's [GREP styles](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/drop-caps-nested-styles.html#create_grep_styles) for that.

First of all, create the character style "option", which is set to your needs (if it doesn't already exist).

Modify the TOC format such that a *right aligned* tab (`\y`) is used before the page number instead of a usual one (`\t`).

Then modify your TOC-entry's paragraph style (if you're using the same as the original paragraph, you need to copy the style, optionally with the original as its base) and select "GREP styles". Here, add a new entry using the "option" format to anything matching
[`(?<=\D\t).+(?=~y\d+$)`](https://regex101.com/r/pN2aD7/3) (click the link for an explanation, except that we're using `~y` to match the right-aligned tab instead of a regular tab). Also *remove* the regular tabulator position of this format!

The RegEx above will match *anything* that your title has after a tab. Alternatively, you can of course simply have it match `\(opt\)` (the parentheses must be `\`-escaped in RegEx).

Comment: Will try, but I haven't been touching InDesign for a long time. Since I was using LaTeX to do all the science documents.

Comment: But the solution seemed pleasing to me

Comment: Yeah, I was about to comment how you could probably achieve this better with LaTeX when I saw you've been more active on TeX.se :D

Comment: LaTeX is better of from making equations into images each time. But I have to use Illustrator to get the images done, Tikz take too long. =)

Comment: You could render Tikz to a PDF once that you then embed then. But I digress... Please let me know when you had an opportunity to test this answer

Comment: Will inform you once I test your solution

Comment: I have tried for another document, which the character style did not apply to the matching.

Comment: InDesign will not display the applied GREP-Style as character style, you'll only see the difference in the output. But rereading your question it seems you're not using a mere text but also an image for which this probably won't work...

Comment: Ah, this time I am using text. So the image thing does not apply anymore.

Comment: And does it work? You may have to modify the GREP if you're not using a Tab for separating the optional part

Comment: I ended up not using GREP but the nested styles. So what I have done is I set the first nested style as NULL with "at most 1 tab mark", then the CHAR-STYLE-YOU-WANT with "in 2 tab marks".

Comment: I was using the Chinese version of Id, so I couldn't figure out what is the best term for tab "mark".

Comment: However, your answer inspired me to use char styles in a paragraph style. Thank you

Comment: Great to hear, you're welcome :)